# % values in css makes image disappear

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I'm having some issues with scaling my elements for responsiveness.

If I am using px values, the scaling is correct and behaves like I want it to. But since I want my mobile css to be compatible with as many devices as possible, I would prefer using % values. The problem is that as soon as I switch my px values to % values, my images/content either disappear or scale to very small proportions and change x & y position as well.

Is there any known issue that could cause browsers to struggle with % values? I've looked around but couldn't find anything that describes my issue.

Example of my issue:

With px values (working correctly): [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aMXkg/4/)

```
.header{
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.logo{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

With % values (image disappears): [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aMXkg/5/)

```
.header{
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.logo{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example of the issue? Percentages work fine on mobiles. Also I would look at revising your meta tag for viewport. Why are you disabling zooming?

Comment: Added the live example. Zooming shouldn't be necessary as the amount of content is limited, and should fit within 75% of the screen.

Comment: `minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0` - disables the users ability to pinch and zoom.

Comment: Removing it doesn't seem to affect my problem in any way.

Comment: No it doesn't, but its considered bad practice to disable zooming: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37511/should-users-be-able-to-zoom-in-a-responsive-webdesign

Comment: When the user scrolls the page all the way down, it scrolls itself back up a bit, so the user can't see the bottom part. Is that by design? Anyway, do you realise that when the width is exactly 600px, you're loading _both_ stylesheets?

Comment: @MrLister Are you talking about desktop? I've made it so when the user scrolls, it automatically animates the view to the nearest page, so the user can't end up inbetween 2 pages. The height of each page should be exactly 100% of your browser height, so u should always be able to see the entire page. What is your browser height? Perhaps the contact content is too long? Thanks for pointing out the 600px width thing.

Comment: Updated question and removed mobile tag. Issue seems to happen on Desktop as well.

Comment: Just an FYI, the "header" div element doesn't have a height.  As such, when the inline-block logo element fills it, its height is zero.

Comment: Yes, on my desktop. I don't have a smartphone here, so I can only test on my desktop machine. My current viewport is 577 pixels high, but it happens with other heights too (although the larger I make the window, the lesser the effect gets), Anyway, if I make the window narrower than 600 pixels, all the content is hidden (because `.content` gets `display:none`). I'm sure that is not by design.

Comment: @MrLister 577px does seem extremely small for desktop. Should I really take such extreme cases into account? I could provide a workaround that this animation is not activated if the viewport height is smaller than the content. About resizing your browser smaller than 600px: I have a mobile css and mobile js that should activate then, but for some reason the mobile css only activates on actual mobile devices and not on resized desktop browsers (I believe the viewport meta tag forces this), unsure how to fix this yet.

Comment: Well, I don't keep all my windows maximised at all times... About the javascript, you could be right; I didn't check that; I assumed that the changed CSS was all that happened on a smaller screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour is absolutely correct. When you use % it means part of the total width of the parent container. In your example which uses % you say "take the whole available area". But the parent container has only width set. So, it gets it's 30% width, but there is no height added. If you add *height: 200px;* (for example) to your *.header* you will see that it works as expected -> http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/aMXkg/11/

```
.header{
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

  .logo{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

Comment: That makes sense, but when I add height: 20%; to the header, it still doesn't work. It only accepts px values? :/

Comment: 20% of the header means that your header will take 20% of its parent container, which probably also doesn't have height set. That's why px work. So, I'll suggest to check the whole DOM tree upwards and see what exactly is going on. If you reach the body, which has *height: 100%* then it is normal to work like that. Consider using min-height property.

Comment: Just figured that out, thanks! Adding 100% height and width to all of my parent elements did the trick.

Comment: Percentage heights are a bit awkward to work with, they only work if the parent container has a height value defined.

Comment: Actually it makes sense. Once you got the idea everything comes to place.